# How to initialize datepickers in base controller?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to avoid having to initialize datepickers in every controller of my application. I would like to have a central place where I initialize my datepickers.

I tried initializing datepickers in my base controller, but it doesn't work - I'm guessing the DOM isn't rendered at that point.

Where should this piece of code be put?

I also tried (in base ctrl)

```
   angular.element(document).ready(function() {

    $('.date-picker').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        setDate: new Date(),
    });

});
```

but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach a `datePicker` directive to your datepicker elements:

```
app.directive("datePickerInit", [function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            $(elem).datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
                setDate: new Date(),
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Then just attach:

```
<input type="date" date-picker-init />
```

Comment: I've never used directives. Where do I put this? Inside a separate file?

Comment: @Tool -- Typically yeah - you can have them in the same file as all of your other Angular if needed tho